# java jna probleme Structure invalid access memory

Tags: java, c, jna

Sorry for my english, i am from france.

I am developing a tool in java and I use **JNA** to call **C** code

I coded the function, it has the following error there:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:383)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
    at $Proxy0.light(Unknown Source)
    at ApicallIn.getpar.main(getpar.java:285)
```

I use several functions, all functions work, but one where there is a structure, this structure is coded as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    double      a_value;
    double      b_value;
    int         ctatus;
} iPoint_Struct;
```

I have to use a function that is:

```
int light( char **light_names, int num_light, int **num_points, iPoint_Struct ***datalightlist);
```

**Java:**

```
public static class iPoint_Struct extends Structure {

 public iPoint_Struct() {}
            public iPoint_Struct(Pointer pointer){
                super(pointer);
                read();
            }
            public List<? > getFieldOrder() {
                return Arrays.asList("a_value", "b_value", "ctatus");
            }


            public static  class sByValue extends getpar.iPoint_Struct implements Structure.ByValue {};
                public double a_value;
                public double b_value;
                public int ctatus;
                public static  class sByReference extends getpar.iPoint_Struct implements Structure.ByReference {};

        }
```

**Function:**

```
if(libe.light( String param_names, int num_params, IntByReference num_points, PointerByReference data_lists )==1){
System.out.println("Ok")
}
```

when I run the function I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:383)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)
at $Proxy0.light(Unknown Source)
at ApicallIn.getpar.main(getpar.java:285)
```

`char**` is used like this :

```
param_names= (char ) malloc( 3000* sizeof( char * ) ); 
for( i = 0; i < 3000; i++ ) { 

param_names[i] = GetName( i ); 
fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", param_names[i] ); } if( light( &param_names[1],1, &numPoints, &data ) != SUCCESS
```

How can write in java? `char**` in java? thank you

Comment: If I read your declaration correctly, `light` is "returning" a pointer to an array of `struct *`, so you're probably incorrectly initializing your Java `Structure` instances when you try to extract the data.

Comment: You think that a code is correcte in java? and can I write char** as String in java ?

Comment: `char**` is *not* a `String` in java.  It might be an array of native string, or a pointer to a pointer, depending on how it's used.  If `param_names` is intended to be an array of native strings, then pass in an array of Java `String`; JNA will automatically convert to an array of `char*` for you, and even throw a NULL on at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in c the char** is used like this : param_names= (char **) malloc( 3000* sizeof( char * ) ); for( i = 0; i < 3000; i++ ) { param_names[i] = GetName( i ); fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", param_names[i] ); } if( light( &param_names[1],1, &numPoints, &data ) != SUCCESS ).... what i can do to write char** in java? thank you

Comment: Update your question.